# PBIS new user login -- need to login with an existing user before

Tags: active-directory

I have a weird problem with PBIS. I have an Ubuntu 16.04 laptop that has to connect to the local AD, allowing people already in the AD to perform their login.
When a user that never used the laptop wants to do his first login, he has to connect the laptop to the cable network (since no wifi is active otherwise), which is fine by me.

The problem I get is that, unless I do a login with a user already existing **on the laptop** (that is, one with which I have already logged in in the past), the system refuses the access.

I have seen no useful information in the logs, the only interesting message is in /var/log/auth.log:

```
May 30 09:45:05 MY_HOSTNAME systemd: pam_sss(systemd-user:account):
Access denied for user AAAA.BBBBB: 10 (User not known to the
underlying authentication module)
```

Then, if I log in and log out with an existing user, I have no login issues until I reboot the machine.

Does anyone have a clue about why this happens?

Thanks a lot in advance!

R.